# Find the surface area of each parallelepiped.

Tags: geometry

Working on the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 281)

> 3. The surface area of a solid is the total of the areas of all its faces. Find the surface area of each parallelepiped above.

[image]

I found the area of top and bottom parallelograms, and also front and back. I a having difficulties understanding how can I find the area of right and left parallelograms ?

Does the area of each side equal $6*10=60$ ? Are right and left figures paralellograms ?

Comment: Let the length of the side you want to find (of the left and right parallelograms (in fact, they are rectangles) be $l$. $\sin(60 ^\circ) = \frac{10}{l}$. Therefore $l = \frac{10}{\sin(60 ^\circ)}$. The areas of the left and right rectangles are therefore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to find the length of marked L

[image]

$A = 2\times 8\times 10 + 2\times 8\times 6 + 2\times 6\times L$

What do we know about $L$?

$L\sin 60^\circ = 10$

Comment: Thank you. $L = \frac{20}{\sqrt{3}}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let the length of the side you want to find of the left and right parallelograms (in fact, they are rectangles) be $l$. Then:

$\sin(60 ^\circ) = \frac{10}{l}$. Therefore $l = \frac{10}{\sin(60 ^\circ)}$. The area of the left and right rectangles are therefore...